# the gulp-pug doesn't work and say unexpected token "indent"

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp, pug

the gulp-pug doesn't work and say unexpected token "indent"

see the images below

[gulp code and nodejs command prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E8H8P.png)

[index.pug and nodejs command prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EoYtr.png)

[package.json and nodejs command prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PNPf9.png)

i use gulp v3.9.1 and node v8.11.3 and npm v6.9.0

i use this version because the course i watch use it and the new versions of gulp and node
and npm is only work with ECMAScript6 and even if i use the lastest versions of gulp and
node and npm and try to use ECMAScript 6 i get the same problem .

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Please never post images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

As the error message *implies*, `head` etc. shouldn't be indented, they should be on the same level as `doctype html` (which makes sense, since the `doctype` tag doesn't hold the rest of the document).

```
doctype html
head
  meta(charset='UTF-8')
  title This Is Pugjs Page
body
  .container This Is Container
```

is correct.